# ruby: Using a variable for module/class name when instantiating

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have an object which needs to be an instance of Foo1 or Foo2, of module Bar1 or Bar2, respectively, based on a condition (let's say, if var1 is non-false/nil). Doing it in eval is rather easy:

```
insty = eval( "bar#{var1 ? '1': '2'}::foo#{var1 ? '1': '2'}.new()")
```

How do I it w/o using an eval? I don't mean the obvious way of:

```
insty = var1 ? Foo1::Bar1.new() : Foo1::Bar2.new()
```

But rather finding a way for, on the fly, making the class name not a constant, but dynamic, if that makes any sense. In TCL, it is very easy done. Yeah, it's a nice-nice to have.

Comment: tl;dr: `Object.const_get`

Comment: Yeah, except it does not handle the "::". The const takes the whole model::class, and I could not not get it to break.

Comment: It does since ruby 2.0. If you're still using an older version (??!) then see the other answers in that post.

Comment: I am using > 2.0.
Never mind. It's a tiny semantics issue. I was thinking TCL, and getting it through to Ruby, which is not a smart thing to do.